# Facebook sdk script load only the first time in an ajax call

Tags: ajax, facebook, button, web2py

In a website i have a left menu that change the right side using ajax. Fine, quick. The right side is a .load file, only this file change.
I would like to give the possibility to the user to share the current view in Facebook. But in this case when the .load file change, Facebook SDK must also reload.
Like on the other parts of the website, I've add:
After :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'MyAppID',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.2'
        });
    };
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And where I want to display Like and Share buttons:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="MyURL" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Facebook SDK load only when the first time, when I load the complete page include the .load page. So fb buttons are not displayed. Is there a way to force Facebook sdk to load ?

Thanks.

Comment: ..the website, I've add: After <body>:

Comment: js console don't return any error

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to load the SDK multiple times (in fact, the code is specifically written to not let you do that).

What you need to do, is tell the SDK that there’s new elements in the DOM, that you want to be parsed into social plugins – and that’s what the [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) method is for.

So call that method after you added new elements to the DOM – either for the whole page, or only for a specific sbu-tree of the DOM, by passing a DOM element reference as parameter.